# Write a macro that unquotes on conditions

Tags: macros, scheme, racket

Given the following forms:

```
(call hello 12 12)
(call hello pos len)
(call hello (+ 1 2 3) len)
```

I want to write a macro that expands to:

```
'(call $hello 12 12)
'(call $hello (world $pos) (world $len))
'(call $hello 6 (world $len))
```

Which means:

- add a $ before identifiers
- add (world) around arguments
- execute anything else normally (e.g. `(+ 1 2 3)` becomes `6`)
- then quote the entire result

This is what I have so far:

```
#lang racket

(require
  (for-syntax racket)
  (for-syntax racket/syntax))

(define-syntax (call stx)
  (define ($ name)
    (format-symbol "$~a" name))

  (define (eval-args args)
    (map (lambda (a)
           (if (identifier? a)
             `(world ,($ a)) ;; quote
             a))             ;; don't quote
         (syntax->list args)))

  (syntax-case stx ()
    ((_ name . args)
       #``(call #,($ #'name) #,@(eval-args #'args)))))


(call hello 12 12)         ;; '(call $hello 12 12)
(call hello pos len)       ;; '(call $hello (world $pos) (world $len))
(call hello (+ 1 2 3) len) ;; '(call $hello (+ 1 2 3) (world $len))
```

As you can see, the form `(+ 1 2 3)` is not evaluated :(

How can I make it so that elements that are not identifiers in my syntax are unquoted, and the rest is quoted? In other words, I just want to prevent some elements (stuff that is not an identifier) from being quoted by my macro.

I tried using `syntax->datum`, `syntax-e`, `eval-syntax` and even `eval` on arguments that are not identifiers, but none can do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unquote the simple identifiers, but using `,a` will invoke a syntax error so you need to spell it out or do the quoting differently:

```
(define (eval-args args)
  (map (lambda (a)
         (if (identifier? a)
           `(world ,($ a))    
           (list 'unquote a))) ;; force unquote
       (syntax->list args)))
```

The expansion:

```
`(call $hello ,(+ 1 2 3) (world $len))
```

Perhaps this is better style:

```
(define (eval-args args)
  (map (lambda (a)
         (if (identifier? a)
             `'(world ,($ a))  ;; quote
             a))               ;; don't quote
       (syntax->list args)))

(syntax-case stx ()
  ((_ name . args)
   #``(call #,($ #'name) ,@(list #,@(eval-args #'args))))))
```

The expansion looks slightly different, but does the same:

```
`(call $hello ,@(list (+ 1 2 3) '(world $len)))
```

Comment: You saved my life with that clever trick! Thanks :)
Is my approach of using an internal helper function in the macro the right thing to do?

Comment: @Jérôme I tend to use `syntax-rules` so I'm a noob when it comes to `syntax-case`. [Greg](http://www.greghendershott.com/fear-of-macros/index.html) is perhaps better suited to answer, but since we have  `begin-for-syntax` I guess its an abstraction and abstraction is good.